How to understand the need for so many tenses in, some kind of, logical way?
I'm a native Polish speaker. I'm 31 and I speak English since I was, probably, 7 or 8. I still don't "get" tenses. I read in English. Fiction and non-fiction. I speak and write. I watch movies. For last 5 years, or so, I work in multinational environments: with Brits, Americans, Dutch, whoever. Currently I'm in the middle of Business English course that is said to be C1 level and I'm doing well.
What I'm trying to say: I get a lot of exposure to the language. Still I just don't "get" English tenses. In my head there's just "past/present/future". I do my homework for the course, I read what are tenses used for, but this knowledge doesn't really stick. I still think in Polish tenses.
Is there some kind of a book, or method to understand it properly so I don't feel like idiot every time I try to understand how and why tenses work? Or do I just shut up and do 100 grammar exercises every week until it sticks? If so: could you recommend a book or some online source for such exercises?

Have you done an online search for 'English tenses'?

Are there certain tenses that cause you particular headaches? Certain situations that you have well in hand? I’m going to guess that one pair that you often find to be a stumbling block are the present perfect and past perfect: it is very, very common for non-native speakers of English to find those two challenging.

"For last 5 years, or so, I work in multinational environments..." is not idiomatic  ;-)

I'd be interested to know how the concept of tense in Polish differs from the English patterns. Maybe one way you can make progress is to find the parallels and connections. How do you think in Polish, and what is the English equivalent?

Tenses are like golf clubs.  You might be able to play with a driver, a putter, and a chipper, but you'd be at a disadvantage.

Lol, in my secondary languages, French and Spanish (which I speak at a low intermediate level, enough to get myself into trouble), I typically go to ridiculous lengths to avoid tenses. I just use participles for past ("I... have gone to your museum today and I think I have left my glasses?") and "going to" for future ("I hope you... are going to find them!"). Or blunder straight through in present tense and rely on the kindness of strangers.

[correction: I have been speaking English since x.]  You have to take the study of tenses one at a time. This question is too broad for this forum. Here is one site, among others. https://live-english.net/guide-english-tenses-intermediate-advanced/

I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad a question for this site.

@PeterKirkpatrick in Polish language there's past, present and future. Order and relations between events don't impact grammar. It doesn't matter if I have just finished doing something or if I started doing something 12 years ago and I'm still not finished with it. There's just past. Similarly there's just present. No present perfect, continuous nor perfect continuous.
So when I think about tenses in English it's hard for me to discern that there're different pasts, or different presents that depend on specifics and relations of events I want to describe.

@PaulTanenbaum I don't have problems expressing myself in any particular situation. I just know that a huge part of my speech is incorrect or not as good as it could be regarding grammar. That's why my question is not that specific.
I'm wondering whether there's some way, textbook, or course that is known to help foreigners understand English grammar. One day I can learn what Present Perfect is for and how to use it, but in my mind, it doesn't make sense so I'll forget the next day and will use tenses at random, based on what sounds right for me at the moment.

@Lambie That's ok. If you think my question is incorrect for this site I understand your decision to vote to close it. Is there some particular rule in the Terms of Service that I broke?

If you look in the Help section, that will explain to you what a good question is. It's under Help at the top right of your screen under the last icon. That said, my advice is this: you need a really good spoken English language coach. Two sessions a week of one hour. You talk to the coach, and they correct you at the end of the session. That's how to fix this situation for you. Good luck!

Thanks for help @Lambie :)


Still I just don't "get" English tenses. ... I still think in Polish tenses.

From what I understand, this is to be expected. Code-switching is hard, and first impressions matter. You can hope to become more accustomed to English patterns, but you might always "think in Polish."

... in some kind of logical way?

Well, language isn't always logical. We attach sounds and letters to ideas, and we might organize those ideas differently. Worse still, languages are not designed from scratch (usually), but evolve. English is especially to blame since it absorbed so many different sources. It has Romance vocabularies with Germanic grammars and everything else mish-mashed together.

Or do I just shut up and do 100 grammar exercises every week until it sticks? ... Could you recommend a book or some online source for such exercises?

At your rather advanced level, I would think you would get more from "immersion" approaches than rote repetition and structured organization. True, you say you've already done such things—read, watch movies, use English in daily situations. But I think, if there's any hope for it feeling more comfortable and easy, that it will come simply by increasing this conversational exposure (or doing it for longer)—that is, using language "for real" in real contexts—than by intensively drilling specific bits of grammar that are somewhat artificially segregated into formal categories.

Let's take the present perfect. It is used for a variety of situations, and  your question brings up one of them: expressing something that began in the past and continues up to the present (and may or may not extend into the future):

For the past five years I have worked in multinational environments.

You are expressing with that tense this notion: "Five years ago I took a job in a multinational environment and since then my work remained in multinational environments."
